# printing values from list not one by one

Tags: java

So I am using List as object and I want to print values.

```
  public List<Entry> getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }
    public void setEntry(List<Entry> entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }
```

I am currently printing them one by one like this:

```
System.out.println(feed.getEntry().get(0).getTitle());
System.out.println(feed.getEntry().get(1).getTitle());
System.out.println(feed.getEntry().get(0));
System.out.println(feed.getEntry().get(1));
```

How do I need to change that I dont need to print one by one them?

Comment: You need a for loop.

Comment: use a loop. for/while/do-while etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print all the entires:

```
feed.getEntry().forEach(System.out::println);
```

To print all the titles:

```
feed.getEntry().stream().map(Entry::getTitle).forEach(System.out::println);
```

To print all entries in the same line separated by spaces:

```
System.out.println(feed.getEntry().stream().collect(joining(" ")));
```

Comment: Thank you to print all titles: ```feed.getEntry().stream().map(Entry::getTitle).forEach(System.out::println);```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Entry> entries = Collections.emptyList();

for (Entry entry : entries)
    System.out.println(entry);
```

Pay attetion on not to call `entries.get()` every time. You have to use `Iterator` instead.